# how to make an odd shaped html/css menu?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

What approach to use to make an odd shaped menu on a website, like attached? Each piece of the circle should be a separate link. Hovering the mouse should be rather precise, especially near the middle. (The absolute 20px middle could be no link at all, if not posible to be 100% precise)

[image]

I've seen irregular menus made using overlapping rectangles, like here: http://www.vanityclaire.com/
Shapes are overlapping, but menu is made from rectangles, a little cheating takes place. However, in my case, the amount of overlapping is too much to use any such technique. Is there any chance to do it in browser/device compatible way, other than just use flash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can do it using CSS3 - see my demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/3116939 //

**EDIT**: **version that also works in IE9** http://dabblet.com/gist/3117278

The idea is to have a div `.pie` with "slices"

```
<ul class="pie">
    <li class="slice" id="s1">
        <a class="slice-contents" href="#slice1"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="slice" id="s2">
        <a class="slice-contents" href="#slice2"></a>
    </li>
<!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

You make the pie to be a disc using `border-radius: 50%;`

You skew and rotate each slice. You bring back the contents of the slices to a non-skewed rectangular shape (which can also prove useful if you want to have text on the slices) and then you set the background.

Comment: It looks very nice in Chrome and FF, but in IE 9 after applying the CSS the list (well, the list dots) disappear. It might be IE does not support transform etc. I tried also -ms-transform but still empty.

Comment: IE9+ does support transforms and I've updated my answer with a version that also works in IE9

Comment: I like this solution! Implemented it on my site and it looks very nice. With help of prefixmycss.com because for some reason, prefixfree library didn't work at all (that may be specific for my site). Thanks for adding this answer, because this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

SVG can do it. But not available in old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [image maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/map), or SVG (with a fallback / polyfill).